# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in with statement suite

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, with-statement

I am running tweak_starfile.py which reads data about nearby stars from a CSV file and massages the data into a form suitable for a star traders type game I am working on.   I am running the program in IDLE.  I put the 'massaging' code inside a with statement, in accord with good practice.  In the with suite, however, `f.close()` generates a `SyntaxError`.  What am I doing wrong?  As far as I can see, the syntax is correct.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# file: tweak_starfile.py
# author: Rick Darwin (c) 2018,2019,2020

import math
import re
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple

RAdpar = namedtuple("RAdpar", "RA2k dec parallax")
Polar3 = namedtuple("Polar3", "theta phi rho")
Vectsm = namedtuple("Vectsm", "sec_per_year motion_angle")
Rect3 = namedtuple("Rect3", "x y z")
Stella = namedtuple("Stella", "nomen idcodes spectral colour abs_mag est_mass num_obj rect3 note")

def tweak_starfile(starcount, csvfile='RECONSNearest110.csv', starfile='starfile_001.dat'):
    """ Read one line from csvfile, unpack to a tuple, massage the data,
        append a new Stella() namedtuple to list starcat.  Repeat till starcount
        records are done, then pickle the resultant starcat.
    """
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
        starcat = []
        linect = 0
        for line in f.readlines():
            if linect == 0:
                pass    # ignore the column heads
            else:
                if linect >= starcount:
                    print('{} records read from {}.  '.format(linect, csvfile))    #DEBUG
                    break
                    #. end if
                    
                # Read in the data
                # Massage the data
                # Make a new tuple
                #. Save the record to the catalog
               
            #. end for
        f.close()     # *** SyntaxError: invalid syntax ***

        #. end with

    # Write out the data
    print('Writing out the data to ./starfile')
    with open(starfile, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dumps(starcat, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        f.close()
        #. end with

    #. end def

def hms2hhhh(hms):
    """ Convert a hms string like '20:30:40.1' or '06 45 08.9' into decimal hours
    (without ValueError on 09 or 08.9, (ie, not treated as oct!)
    """
    suite
    #. end def

def hhh2rad(hhh):
    """ Convert decimal hours to radians
    """
    suite 
    #. end def

def starcolour(spectra):
    """ Return a 3tuple from a color picker; spectral holds a string like 'M5.0 V'
    """
    print('In starcolour')
    sc = spectra[0]
    dicto = {
        'O': (0, 153, 255),        # blue
        'B': (102, 204, 255),      # blue-white
        'A': (255, 255, 255),      # white
        'F': (255, 255, 153),      # yellow-white
        'G': (255, 255, 0),        # yellow
        'K': (255, 153, 0),        # orange
        'M': (192, 51, 0),         # red
        'D': (255, 0, 0)           # deep red
        }
    return dicto[sc] if sc in dicto.keys() else (0, 255, 255)     # cyan! why not?
    #. end def

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tweak_starfile(110, "RECONSNearest110.csv", "starfile_001.dat")
```

Comment: For one, please post the full error. Second, you don't need `f.close()` at all when using `with`. Lastly, I didn't get any syntax error from your code...

Comment: Thank you, Tomerikoo.  I should have posted the full code: I found an error in a print/format statement, not enough closing parentheses, just before the f.close().

Comment: Yep, syntax errors sometimes are one line before where they are indicated. Anyway remember there is no need for `f.close()`!